# Style google search result like stackoverflow using microformat

Tags: html, seo, vcf-vcard, hcard

It's for a while I'm researching on the `microformat` for styling my site information different in google result page.
I found some detail about microformat in this links:
http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-authoring#The_Importance_of_Names
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-microformats-magic-to-your-site
http://microformats.org/get-started

`that will have result like this :`
[image]

Now, I'm trying to find out ***could I manipulate microformats to force google show my site information in result page, just like do it for `stackoverflow` or `other most popular sites :`*** 
[image]

Or ***`Is it possible to do that...?!?!?`***
**Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force Google to show your website and sub pages like the Stack Overflow example you posted. Your search term was stackoverflow and so the information displayed on the results page was far and away the most relevant. Hence why it displays like that.

If someone searched for your website by name you might get a result like that. You'll need to submit an xml sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools, give it time to index and hopefully your website name will be unique enough.

I guess the main thing is that your website is first on Google's results page for a given search term and the sitemap shows Google what your other pages are.

With respect to microdata - it's really good for giving extra information to search engines. The CSS-tricks one is a perfect example. You'd need a Google+ profile and using the microdata specify that profile as the author.

Again, Webmaster Tools has some great Microdata validation tools. You can even load your pages source code up, highlight the text you want to tag and it'll show you exactly what tags to add and how so it works. Link below:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/

Comment: Thank you... I guess that is not possible, but about sitemap, I didn't understand your mean, because I developed a site and was made a sitemap, and this site was in top3 in google search when related keywords was searched, but the result was just like other one... Did  I get your mean in wrong way?